# Partial View's JavaScript only changing first Partial

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor, partial-views

I have a partial view that contains some JavaScript, this partial view can be displayed multiple times on a webpage. However, when it is displayed multiple times, the JavaScript only works for the first instance of the partial view. I want the JavaScript to affect only its own partial view, so when I change `SourceFormSelect`. Here is my Partial View's HTML:

```html
<div id="AddMedia">
    <form>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-6 dropdown my-2 px-0">
                    <label class="control-label">Source:<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                    <select id="SourceFromSelect" asp-for="Medias.SourceFrom" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(SourceFromEnum))" style="width:85%;" class="btn border-dark" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <option class="dropdown-item" selected>Select</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Medias.SourceFrom" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-5">
                    <div id="MediaFile" class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Pick a File</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                    </div>
                    <div id="MediaLink" class="form-group">
                        <label for="url">Link the Media</label>
                        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is the script for it:

```js
 document.getElementById("mediaFile").style.display = "none";

    $('#SourceFromSelect').change(function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("SourceFormSelect");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (strUser == 6) {
            document.getElementById("mediaFile").style.display = "inline-block";
            document.getElementById("mediaLink").style.display = "none";           
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("mediaFile").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("mediaLink").style.display = "inline-block";           
        }
    })
```

Finally here is where I call the Partial view:

```html
<div id="MediaList">
        @for (i = 0; i < MediaCount; ++i)
        {
            <partial name="_MediaPartial" />
        }
</div>
```

Comment: Do not to use IDs for multiple items. Consider using "event delegation".

Comment: I am unfamiliar with event delegation, how could I use it here?

Comment: https://javascript.info/event-delegation it's used when the underlying HTMl might change.

Comment: I've spent the past 2 hours ish looking at event delegation, but I can't get it working for my issue. Could you post an answer showing how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing my ids to classes (thanks for the suggestion) and changing my JavaScript to the following:

```js
 $('.MediaFile').css('display', 'none');

    $('.AddMedia').on('change', 'select', function (e) {
        //console.log($(this).parents(".AddMedia"));
        changeFile(e, $(this).parents(".AddMedia"));
    });

    function changeFile(e, parent) {
        // console.log(e, parent);
        let el = e.target;
        var strUser = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
        console.log(el, parent.find('.MediaFile'));
        if (strUser == "Phone or Computer") {
            parent.find('.MediaFile').css('display', 'inline-block');
            parent.find('.MediaLink').css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            parent.find('.MediaLink').css('display', 'inline-block');
            parent.find('.MediaFile').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

bro! You have identifiers id="MediaFile", and id="MediaLink" in your partial view. If you load all the partial views in your div (the one with id="MediaList"), you will end up with multiple divs with id="MediaFile" and id="MediaLink".

Accoring to html nature, ids are given to the elements should be unique, which are not in your case. That's why, your JavaScript code only works with the first partial view.

I would recommend you to give unique ids for each of the partial view divs instead of id="MediaFile" and id="MediaLink".

Hope, this answers to your question.